# can't find struct in a same package

Tags: go, glide-golang

suddenly, vscode cannot get access struct in the same package,but different files.

the error showed undefined struct

Previously vscode was able to instantiate struct across files(vscode+go1.12.4)

the sample code like this:

file1 a.go

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

type su struct {
    Sfd string
    Sf  int
}

func (sed *su) do() {
    fmt.Println(sed.Sfd + string(sed.Sf))
}
```

file2 main.go

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    d := su{}
    fmt.Println(d)
}
```

these two files are in the same package

have some one met the same problem?

Comment: [The code compiles and runs in the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/oPuThk4FvzQ).

Comment: try go run *.go

Comment: yes, it can work in playground, but why have trouble in vscode

Comment: @Wicak `go run` with file names is mostly misused. For people that really want to use `go run` rather than `go build` or `go install` they they can use a package name argument (with recent versions of Go at least): `go run .` (The biggest difference is that this respects build tags, *`_test.go` files, etc where-as `go run *.go` will fail in many perfectly valid packages).

Comment: Thanks @DaveC, i don't know this before. But most of answer i found, suggested to use go run *.go for solve the problems like this. Would you like give me more suggestion like article, etc about this problems ?

Comment: Thanks @DaveC，So how to deal this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the language server sometimes crashes. Open the Command Palette and type „language server“. A command should be shown that says „restart language server“. Restarting VSCode might be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

In GoLand, you can change the Run kind from file to Package.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue. It is enough to point to the type (in your case `su`) by using package name before. For example: `d := mypackage.su{}` (even though you use it from the same package but different source file). It worked in my case and for some reason GoLand IDE did not suggest such solution.

Comment: This absolutely worked!
I am new to Go, so maybe this is just basic understanding, but my "package" is defined at a first-level directory under root, then I have sub folders under that, which also use the same "package" name. The sub folders cannot see the parent folder's types. Same package, only not really the same package?